# Downloading projects from github in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-extensions

Was just wondering if this is possible with an extension.

I realize that that vs uses nuget with powershell but some of the github projects are not on nuget and it would be nice to quickly write a command had have the js files downloaded into the project files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org), you can use [Bower](http://bower.io/) for managing client libraries in your project and keep NuGet only for managing .NET libraries.

Sample video: http://blog.lambda3.com.br/2013/12/bower-e-npm-na-linha-de-comando-dentro-do-visual-studio-instalado-via-nuget/

Also take a look at this project template > 
**[ASP.NET Solution](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/359f4304-57d7-4178-9cab-165e2090dce2)** < on Visual Studio Gallery

It has a Node.js friendly directory layout and can be used as a starting point if you want to play with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (or [Gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/)) and [Bower](http://bower.io/) automation tools.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is definitely possible!

Starting with Visual Studio 2012 Microsoft created extensions that allow you to use any Git repository available and work with it directly from within Visual Studio.

In Visual Studio 2012 this requires an extension ([found here in the gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c)). In Visual Studio 2013 this is fully incorporated in the product.